# Looping through a dictionary (grocery lists)

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

In my intro to scripting class the idea is to create a basic grocery list that takes input from the user in the form of (item, quantity, price). You store those in a dictionary, and then ask the user if they want to add more items to the list or quit. If they add more to the list, the script wants you to add it to a "list", where the dictionary entry is nested. When the user quits the program, it is supposed to print out something of this nature.

```
2 milk at $2.99 ea for a total of: x  
1 eggs at 1.99 ea for a total of: x  
Grand total: x
```

My problem is: I can get it to print out in this manner, however it will **only** print out the same line over and over again. I have checked that it does add the entries to the `grocery_history` list. They are there, but when I loop over it to print them out, it will only print out the first entry, for every item in the list.

```
i.e. 
2 milk at $2.99 ea for a total of: x  
2 milk at $2.99 ea for a total of: x  
grand total: x
```

I am not very good with lists or dictionaries. They are one of the one things in coding that I'm struggling with.

I've tried to increase the index value of the list, and it threw an error.

```py
#Task: Create the empty data structure
grocery_item = {}

grocery_history = []
#Variable used to check if the while loop condition is met
stop = 'go'
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':
    item_name = input('Item name: ')
    quantity = int(input('Quantity purhcased: '))
    cost = float(input('Price per item: '))
    GL={'name':item_name, 'number': int(quantity), 'price':float(cost)}
    grocery_item.update(GL)
    print(GL)
    grocery_history.append(GL)
    choice = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
    if choice == 'q':
        #print(grocery_history)
        break
    elif choice =='c':
        continue
print(grocery_history)

grand_total = 0

#Define a 'for' loop.

total = 0
rows = len(grocery_history)
for i in grocery_history:
    #Calculate the total cost for the grocery_item.
    item_total = grocery_history[0]['number']*grocery_history[0]['price']
    #Output the information for the grocery item to match this example:
    print(grocery_history[0]['number'], grocery_history[0]['name'], ' @', '$',grocery_history[0]['price'], ' ea', '$', item_total)
    #Add the item_total to the grand_total
    grand_total += item_total
    item_total = 0

#Print the grand total
print(grand_total)
```

Comment: `grocery_history` appears to be a list of dicts. When you iterate over it, `i` will be a dict. In your loop you're always looking at the first item in `grocery_history`. Try using `i` instead.

Comment: thanks @afro, I cant believe it was that simple. well, actually I can. because again, I suck at dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a for-loop over `i`, but you don't actually use `i` anywhere in the loop. All those `grocery_history[0]` should be `i`. You should also give it a more descriptive name, such as `item`. And you don't need to reset `item_total` to zero.

```
for item in grocery_history:
  item_total = item['number']*item['price']
  print(item['number'], 
        item['name'], ' @', '$',
        item['price'], ' ea', '$', 
        item_total)
  grand_total += item_total
```

Comment: I appreciate the assist. to be honest I wasn't aware that  I had to use the variable I in the for loop. but that does make sense.

Comment: @AustinHoward There are cases where the iterator isn't used in the for-loop, but if your code only involves things that don't change, then you're going to get the same output each time.